# Meaning of equal in cumulative probability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions

Suppose X and Y have a joint density function $f(x,y)$. What is the meaning of

$P(X<0.5,Y=0.25)$ say?

Is it

$$P(X<0.5,Y=0.25)=\int_{-\infty}^{0.5}dx f(x,0.25)$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lower limit should be $-\infty$ and there should be a $dy$ integral ranging from $0.25$ to $0.25$. Thus the desired quantity will be just zero.

Answer (score 2):

To reinforce the other answer you've already received: if you want to integrate the probability, it's still a double integral, just as it would be for something like $P(X<0.5,Y<0.25)$, but with bounds on $y$ that result in zero probability.

Another way to get the same result is:
$$
P(X<0.5,Y=0.25) \leq P(Y=0.25) = 0.
$$